# android os deletes my files when battery drain?

Tags: android, file, internal, battery

I have developed small application contains long running Service which listening to incoming UDP messages.

I'm saving some of my data to my internal storage.

Usualy everything goes fine, and i can get back my data from the internal storage even after reboot.

Yesterday my application was running and the battery drained. 
I've noticed that some of my data in the internal storage gone.

Does android delete my files when battery drained?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnt , unless you personally "clear app data " from settings .